# How to convert UTC timezone to CET timezone in groovy script

Tags: groovy, timezone

Input date sample in UTC:'2021-08-31T22:00:00Z'
Output date format in CET: 'DD-MM-YYYY'

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

```java
Instant
        .parse( "2021-08-31T22:00:00Z" )                      // Returns a `Instant` object, a moment as seen in UTC.
        .atZone(                                              // Adjust from UTC to a specific time zone.
                ZoneId.of( "Europe/Stockholm" )
        )                                                     // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
        .format(                                              // Generate text representing the value of our `ZonedDateTime` object. 
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uuuu" )   // Or consider using `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate` for localization.
        )                                                     // Returns a `String` object.
```

We see the date flip over from the 31st to the 1st.

> 01-09-2021

## Details

In Java syntax… (I don’t know Groovy)

Convert your string input to `Instant`, as both represent a moment in UTC with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2021-08-31T22:00:00Z" ) ;
```

Define the time zone to which you want to adjust. The 2-4 letter pseudo-zones such as `CET`, `CST`, `IST` are not actually time zones. A [real time zone](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) is named in format of `Continent/Region`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Berlin" ) ;
```

Adjust from UTC to zone by applying the `ZoneId` to `Instant` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Extract the date only.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

Generate text by using `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern`.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uuuu" ) ;
String output = ld.format( f ) ;
```

Example code.

```java
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2021-08-31T22:00:00Z" );
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Stockholm" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate();
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uuuu" );
String output = ld.format( f );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/dpVDYe).

> 01-09-2021

We could skip the `.toLocalDate` technically.

Comment: Hi Basil,
Instant instant = Instant.parse(arg1);
   zoneId z =  ZoneId.of("Europe/Stockholm");
   ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(z) ;
   LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
   DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu") ;
String output = ld.format(f) ;
return output;

Am i making any mistake in above code, i am getting error like
 No signature of method: java.time.ZonedDateTime.format() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [dd-MM-yyyy]

Comment: @GOPAL_KS Your code runs, after fixing typo. See the [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/dpVDYe). I added the code as an example at bottom of my Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing as Basil, but with the CET lookup:

```
import java.time.*

String input = '2021-08-31T22:00:00Z'

String output = ZonedDateTime.parse(input)
    .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"))
    .format("dd-MM-yyyy")
```

You *could* do

```
    .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("CET"))
```

But as Basil rightly says, using these shortened forms are not recommended

Comment: The pseudo-zones can only be guessed, as they are not standardized and are not unique. For example, `IST` is India Standard Time as well as Irish Standard time. And `CST` is both Central Standard Time (in the Americas) as well as China Standard Time. Depending on the pseudo-zones is a bad habit that will likely lead to errors and regret.

Comment: Very true, I've updated my answer (and upvoted yours for being more correct first time) 